# Keep the latest 7 records and delete all other query issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mytable` (
  `i_contact_id` int(16) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `s_contact_name` char(48) NOT NULL,
  `ts_contact_scraped` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Date Time when contact is last scraped.',
  PRIMARY KEY (`i_contact_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

INSERT INTO `mytable` (`i_contact_id`, `s_contact_name`, `ts_contact_scraped`) VALUES
(1, 'aaaa', '2018-07-27 02:30:30'),
(2, 'bbbb', '2017-03-28 04:13:08'),
(3, 'cccc', '2017-03-12 03:52:57'),
(4, 'dddd', '2017-04-18 07:13:34'),
(5, 'eeee', '2018-05-29 15:22:23'),
(6, 'ffff', '2018-02-23 13:27:24'),
(7, 'gggg', '2016-10-17 22:50:24'),
(8, 'hhhh', '2018-07-20 14:02:14'),
(9, 'iiii', '2020-03-24 10:56:02');
```

I want to keep 7 latest rows and delete all oldest rows based on `ts_contact_scraped` field but it don't work properly.

Here is my delete query

```
DELETE FROM `mytable`
  WHERE i_contact_id <= (
    SELECT i_contact_id
    FROM (
      SELECT i_contact_id
      FROM `mytable`
      ORDER BY ts_contact_scraped DESC
      LIMIT 1 OFFSET 7
    ) foo
  )
```

My original table has more than 1100000 rows, I want to run above query periodically using PHP to purge oldest rows, there is some other logic involved so I want to delete the oldest rows based on `ts_contact_scraped` field.

When I run this query on my original table it deletes more than expected rows.

Here is fiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9414e2/1/0

Comment: It might be more efficient to create a new table, retaining just the rows you want to keep

Comment: I don't want to create new table each time.

Comment: Can you help me with any good working solution?

Comment: @Syed: What Strawberry means is: create a new table with the seven rows, drop the original table, rename the new table to the original table's name. If your table contains as many rows as you suggest, a delete statement deleting everything but seven rows can be awfully slow.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner In my original table having 1100K rows approximately, when I add 25 rows than I have to delete 25 rows.

Comment: Latest - this is by DATETIME. But you join by PRIMARY KEY whereas these two orderings differs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JOIN`:

```
DELETE t
    FROM `mytable` t JOIN 
         (SELECT i_contact_id
          FROM `mytable`
          ORDER BY ts_contact_scraped DESC
          LIMIT 1 OFFSET 7
         ) tt
         ON tt.i_contact_id = t.i_contact_id
```

Comment: Is it more efficient than my query?

Comment: @Syed . . . (1) You would have to test to see if it more efficient.  (2) "It does not work" is a useless comment.  Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

In your delete statement you are relying on a higher `ts_contact_scraped` also meaning a higher `i_contact_id`. At least in your example this is not given.

So stick to `ts_contact_scraped` instead:

```
DELETE FROM `mytable`
  WHERE ts_contact_scraped <= (
    SELECT ts_contact_scraped
    FROM (
      SELECT ts_contact_scraped
      FROM `mytable`
      ORDER BY ts_contact_scraped DESC
      LIMIT 1 OFFSET 7
    ) foo
  );
```

Here is your altered fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/610cb4/1

(If there can be duplicate `ts_contact_scraped`, though, things will get more complicated.)

Answer (score 0):

```sql
DELETE t1.*
FROM `mytable` t1
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT i_contact_id
            FROM `mytable`
            ORDER BY ts_contact_scraped DESC
            LIMIT 7 ) t2 ON t1.i_contact_id = t2.i_contact_id
WHERE t2.i_contact_id IS NULL;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=112fc8e7dd8e6a6855bdfdb7a37b7f91)

or

```sql
DELETE t1.*
FROM `mytable` t1, ( SELECT ts_contact_scraped
                     FROM `mytable`
                     ORDER BY ts_contact_scraped DESC
                     LIMIT 1 OFFSET 7 ) t2
WHERE t1.ts_contact_scraped <= t2.ts_contact_scraped;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ece7caa8c8d5725927816060e0dc2c1e)